# how to check which button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

this is my view i am submitted form using jquery,then I want to check which button is clicked either 'ADD PRODUCT' or SUBMIT button in controller

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('itemcontroller/submit'); ?>

   <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="add-name">
            <label>Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" placeholder="Product name">
            <span id="pnerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Product Name</span> 
         </div>
         <div class="add-name">                                            
            <label>Product Image</label>
             <input type="file" id="user_file" name="user_file">
             <span id="imgerror" style="display: none;">Please select an Image</span> 
          </div>
         <div class="add-name">
             <label>Product Category</label>
             <?php  $attributes = 'id="cat"';
             echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat, set_value('cat'), $attributes); ?>
             <span id="caterror" style="display: none;">Please select Category</span> 
          </div>


          </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="add-name">

          </div>
          <div class="add-name">
             <label>Product Description</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="product_description" name="product_description" placeholder="Product Description"></textarea>
             <span id="pderror" style="display: none;">Please enter Product Description</span> 
          </div>

    </div>

     <div class="sub-add">
         <button type="submit" form="form1" id="fill" name="fill" value="add">ADD PRODUCT</button>

     </div>
     <div class="sub-add">
          <button type="submit" id="go" name="go" form="form1" value="go">SUBMIT</button>

     </div>


     <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

this is my jquery code for ADD PRODUCT button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fill').click(function(event){
         var product_name = $('#product_name').val();
         var image = $('#user_file').val();
         var cat = $('#cat').val();
         var product_description = $('#product_description').val();
         if(product_name.length == 0)
         {
             $('#pnerror').show();
         }
         if(image.length == 0)
         {
             $('#imgerror').show();
         }
         if(cat == 0)
         {
             $('#caterror').show();
         }
         if(product_description.length == 0)
         {
             $('#pderror').show();
         }
         else if(product_name.length != 0 && image.length != 0 && cat != 0 && product_description.length != 0)
         {            
            var $target = $( event.target );
            $target.closest("form").submit();            
         }
        });
</script>
```

this is my SUBMIT button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#go').click(function(event){

         var product_name = $('#product_name').val();
         var user_file = $('#user_file').val();
         var cat = $('#cat').val();
         var product_description = $('#product_description').val();
         if(product_name.length == 0)
         {
             $('#pnerror').show();
         }
         if(user_file.length == 0)
         {
             $('#imgerror').show();
         }
         if(cat == 0)
         {
             $('#caterror').show();
         }
         if(product_description.length == 0)
         {
             $('#pderror').show();
         }
         else if(product_name.length != 0 && user_file.length != 0 && cat != 0 && product_description.length != 0)
         {            
            var $target = $( event.target );
            $target.closest("form").submit();            
         }
        });
</script>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function submit()
    {  
        print_r($_POST);
        if($this->input->post('go'))
        {
            $config['upload_path']          = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 2048;
            $config['max_height']           = 1024;        

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('user_file'))
            {
                $data = array('prod_data' => $this->upload->data());             
                $user_file = $data['prod_data']['raw_name']."".$data['prod_data']['file_ext'];
                $id = $this->session->userdata['record']['id'];
                $com_id = $this->session->userdata['record']['com_id'];

                $sam = array(
                            'title' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
                            'type' => 'product'                       
                            );
                $this->load->model('registermodel');
                $chk = $this->registermodel->insertsam($sam);
                if ($chk == TRUE)
                {
                    $id = $this->registermodel->getsampleid();
                    $data = array(
                            'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
                            'image' => 'images/'.$user_file,
                            'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description'),
                            'cat_id' => $this->input->post('cat'),
                            'com_id' => $com_id,
                            'id' => $id
                            );
                    $check = $this->registermodel->insertproduct($data);
                    if($check == TRUE)
                    {
                        echo "<script>
                                alert('Data Submitted Succesfully');
                            </script>";  
                        redirect('/homecontroller');
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "Value insertion Failed";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error);
            }
        }
        else if($this->input->post('fill'))
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 2048;
                $config['max_height']           = 1024;        

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('user_file'))
                {
                    $data = array('prod_data' => $this->upload->data());             
                    $user_file = $data['prod_data']['raw_name']."".$data['prod_data']['file_ext'];
                    $id = $this->session->userdata['record']['id'];
                    $com_id = $this->session->userdata['record']['com_id'];

                    $sam = array(
                            'title' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
                            'type' => 'product'                       
                            );
                    $this->load->model('registermodel');
                    $chk = $this->registermodel->insertsam($sam);
                    if ($chk == TRUE)
                    {
                        $id = $this->registermodel->getsampleid();
                        $data = array(
                                'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
                                'image' => 'images/'.$user_file,
                                'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description'),
                                'cat_id' => $this->input->post('cat'),
                                'com_id' => $com_id,
                                'id' => $id
                                );
                        $check = $this->registermodel->insertproduct($data);
                        if($check == TRUE)
                        {
                            echo "<script>
                                alert('Product added Succesfully');
                            </script>";
                            $data['category'] = $this->linkmodel->get_category();
                            $data['cat'] = $this->registermodel->get_category();
                            $this->load->view('itemview',$data);                 
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "Value insertion Failed";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    print_r($error);
                }
            }
    }
```

print_r($_POST); 
this returns only this :
Array ( [product_name] => Multifunction Printer Machine [cat] => 82 [product_description] => Approx Price: Rs 80,000 / Piece)

not return ADD PRODUCT OR SUBMIT button name, please anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `<input type="submit" ...>` instead of `<button ...>`. It should append buttons' name and value to `$_POST`.

Comment: it's not working sir, I am change <button ...> into <input type="submit" ,but it does not get the solutions, but thanks for your advice sir

Answer (score 0):

Add `input` `hidden` field in your form and set different value in each JavaScript code.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('itemcontroller/submit'); ?>
<!-- your existing code --->


<input type="hidden" name="submit_type" id="submit_type" value="" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

JavaScript code Modification

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#go').click(function(event){
        <!-- your existing code --->

           $('#submit_type').val('SUBMIT');
           var $target = $( event.target );
            $target.closest("form").submit();            
         }
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fill').click(function(event){
        <!-- your existing code --->

           $('#submit_type').val('ADD PRODUCT');
           var $target = $( event.target );
            $target.closest("form").submit();            
         }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Now please mark that as accept answer:- where to mark sir , I am new on stackoverflow.com, please give me suggetions to mark

Comment: Check help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Or 
http://prntscr.com/hft9ky